# PHP String Replace/Append

Tags: php, string, logic

I am trying out a Logic in strings but facing difficulties in string manipulation functions. Which function will be good for this below approach:

My String is "Hello" I want to add "------------------" after the first string that is "Hello--------------" and the length of the string should be 20 after the string manipulation.

> I want to add "------------------" to the string to make it 20 length.

In other words: `Hello+Underscores`

If the string length is too much we can trim the string.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
<?php
$challenge = 'hello'; 

$length = strlen($challenge);

$i= $length +1;
$challenge=substr($challenge,0,$i);

echo  $challenge.'<br>';

?>
```

I tried string concatenation but I am sure I cant use it in this logic, I think the string adding should be done with `preg_replace`.

Can some one give a good advice on it!

Comment: if string is 5 chars and you add 1 it will still only be 6 chars long, what do you want to add to make it 20 chars long?

Comment: What if the string length is less than 20.What charcters do you want to add to make the string length 20.?

Comment: _and the length of the string should be 20 after the string manipulation_ .. 20 chars with what exactly? Hello+Underscores?

Comment: I added sone "--------------" but the SO editor deleted it.. kindly check my edited code.

Comment: can you check the updated question..

Comment: [`echo str_pad('hello', 20, '_');`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: @dbf yes.. Hello+Underscores

Comment: @Yoshi I think you can post your answer it is correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-pad.php).

```
$input = 'hello';
$output = str_pad($input, 20, '_');
echo $output;
```

demo: http://ideone.com/0EPoV2

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi I learnt many way to do the operation.. Yours is too easy to understand..

Answer (score 3):

[str-pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is the easiest way to achieve your task and code sample as follows.

```
 <?php
 $input = "Alien";
 echo str_pad($input, 10);                      // produces "Alien     "
 echo str_pad($input, 10, "-=", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // produces "-=-=-Alien"
 echo str_pad($input, 10, "_", STR_PAD_BOTH);   // produces "__Alien___"
 echo str_pad($input, 6 , "___");               // produces "Alien_"
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
<?php
    $string = "anything";

    echo substr($string."------------------------------------------",0,20);
?>
```

Just use the first 20 chars of your string and ------------------------

Edit based on new requirement not given in original question for some reason.

```
<?php
    $string = "anything";
    $newstring = substr($string."------------------------------------------",0,20);
    echo $newstring."whatever you want to add at end";
?>
```

Comment: It works fine what if I want to add string at end of the --------string?

Comment: Thank you for your Valuable time and logic.. But its a bit fuzzy.. but I learnt for your code..

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php
$input = "HELLO";
echo str_pad($input, 10, "----", STR_PAD_RIGHT); 
?>
```

here `$input` is string and `10` is length of char added  **STR_PAD_RIGHT** is position

View this link [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Hello';
$str .= "_";
while(strlen($str) <= 20){
$str .= "-";
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: Your logic works the same but the loop is a bit difficult.. all the time.. Thank you so much for your logic..

Comment: Yes I do understand but str_pad($input, 20, '_'); does it with out much work. Sorry I just shown it from one of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$challenge = 'hello';

$length = strlen($challenge);
if($length < 20){
    $limit = 20-$length;
    for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++){
        $challenge .= '_';
    }
}
echo $challenge;
```

Comment: if you give and then it will echo and+17_ like and________________, so the count is still 20. and's length 3, _ length 17.

Comment: @Sudhhakar The code works as expected but too many loops slow down my process as I am using this logic while page load it slowing the process.. Thanks for your logic and time.. It helped me.. to thnk about various logic..